# How to enable Tcp\Ip remote connections in Centos 7.0

Tags: centos, tcp

I am running Centos 7.0 using VMPlayer . I have set a private network shared with the host (Windows 7) .
On my Centos Server i have opened a tcp listener on port 10102 .
I could not connect to this endpoint . 
Someone have an idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you test it with Hercules or anythings else?

Comment: Did you check Windows firewall and Linux iptables?
I suggest try "service iptables stop "